# On Press listener blocks parent Component PanResponder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a `Animated.View` Component which has a `PanResponder` to make it draggable.
This `Animated.View` Component has a `Text` child which has the `onLongPress` event listener set to perform some action later on...

The problem is that it seams like the `onLongPress` event listener is also "capturing" the normal press action(which is needed for the `PanResponder` too.

Is it possible to pass the normal onPress of the `Text` to the PanResponder, cancel it or trigger `onStartShouldSetPanResponder` manually, to not interrupt the `PanResponder` unless it's an actual long press?

contructor

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showDraggable: true,
      dropAreaValues: null,
      pan: new Animated.ValueXY(),
      opacity: new Animated.Value(1),
      text: "Hello World"
    };
    this._val = { x: 0, y: 0 };
    this.state.pan.addListener(value => (this._val = value));

    this.panResponder = PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (e, gesture) => true,
      onPanResponderGrant: (e, gesture) => {
        this.state.pan.setOffset({
          x: this._val.x,
          y: this._val.y
        });
        this.state.pan.setValue({ x: 0, y: 0 });
      },
      onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([
        null,
        { dx: this.state.pan.x, dy: this.state.pan.y }
      ])
    });
  }
```

render

```js
render() {
    const panStyle = {
      transform: this.state.pan.getTranslateTransform()
    };
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          top: this.props.top
        }}
      >
     <Animated.View {...this.panResponder.panHandlers} style={[panStyle]}>
     <View style={{ zIndex: 250,
        padding: 10,
          borderWidth: 2,
          borderColor: "yellow"}}>

          <Text style={{fontSize: 24}} onLongPress={() => {
              console.log("Long press recognized")
          }}>{this.state.text}</Text>
          </View>
        </Animated.View> 
      </View>
    );
  }
```

(The border is to make the Views boundaries visible and is not of importance regarding the question)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use `Animated.Text`
it works with the `PanResponder`.